# Apply custom Item Template to Promoted Results

Tags: 2013, display-template, sharepoint-search, promoted-results

We have hybrid search enabled in our SharePoint search environment where-in we are displaying federated search results from SharePoint Online tenant in our on-premise Search site. We display few top SharePoint results as promoted results block in the results page. I now have a requirement for displaying top people results from SharePoint Online people results as promoted results block. I am able to display the same but when I try to apply a custom item template for displaying the results in promoted results block it doesn't get applied. It still takes the default item template.

I tried creating results types at site collection and site level, tried creating query rule at central admin, site collection level without luck and success. Is this a limitation or am I missing anything?